# swt/rmi java-application doesn't shut down properly on mac/OSX

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, swt, rmi

i have an SWT Application which uses RMI. Only on mac/cocoa it won't shut down properly. I closed everything, shutdown the executor-service I use, but it won't quit.

This is my ThreadDump:

```
2012-01-03 17:48:56
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02-402 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=5 tid=7ffa65000800 nid=0x10136c000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(2)-192.168.247.101" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa66128000 nid=0x10ecdd000 runnable [10ecdc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    - locked <7e0b8a0a0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:517)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <7e0989490> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=2 tid=7ffa66059000 nid=0x10ebda000 in Object.wait() [10ebd9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7defe4f00> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:100)
    - locked <7defe4f00> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI RenewClean-[busta-hl.dyndns.info:12000]" daemon prio=5 tid=7ffa6606f000 nid=0x10ead7000 in Object.wait() [10ead6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7defe4c50> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <7defe4c50> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread.run(DGCClient.java:516)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=5 tid=7ffa651c8000 nid=0x10e9d4000 in Object.wait() [10e9d3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7df07f988> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(AWTAutoShutdown.java:265)
    - locked <7df07f988> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JMX server connection timeout 21" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa629dd000 nid=0x10c7c8000 in Object.wait() [10c7c7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7df0345e0> (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:150)
    - locked <7df0345e0> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa62b71000 nid=0x10c6c5000 waiting on condition [10c6c4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <7df01ce80> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.247.101" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa65380000 nid=0x10c5c2000 runnable [10c5c1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    - locked <7dbef48f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:517)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <7df036b48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa651ce000 nid=0x10c4bf000 runnable [10c4be000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <7df01d030> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:34)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa661ea800 nid=0x109c7d000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Timer-0" daemon prio=5 tid=7ffa628dd000 nid=0x109a77000 in Object.wait() [109a76000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7dee02000> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:483)
    - locked <7dee02000> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin" daemon prio=1 tid=7ffa65279000 nid=0x109643000 waiting on condition [109642000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$TokenPoller.run(SunPKCS11.java:692)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Thread-1" daemon prio=5 tid=7ffa65101800 nid=0x7fff7d891960 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=5 tid=7ffa650ef000 nid=0x10917f000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa650ee800 nid=0x10907c000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa650ed800 nid=0x108f79000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=9 tid=7ffa650ed000 nid=0x108e76000 runnable [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon prio=5 tid=7ffa650ec000 nid=0x108d73000 waiting on condition [00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=7ffa6280e000 nid=0x108ab1000 in Object.wait() [108ab0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7dee000f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <7dee000f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=7ffa6280d000 nid=0x1089ae000 in Object.wait() [1089ad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <7dee00108> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <7dee00108> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=9 tid=7ffa62808800 nid=0x1088ab000 runnable 

"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7ffa65002000 nid=0x1046a5000 runnable 

"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7ffa65002800 nid=0x1047a8000 runnable 

"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7ffa65003000 nid=0x1048ab000 runnable 

"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=9 tid=7ffa65004000 nid=0x1049ae000 runnable 

"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" prio=9 tid=7ffa6507f000 nid=0x108551000 runnable 
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=7ffa65101000 nid=0x109282000 waiting on condition 

"Exception Catcher Thread" prio=10 tid=7ffa65001800 nid=0x1014ce000 runnable 
JNI global references: 1185
```

**EDIT**: Forgot the last part:

```
JNI global references: 1127

Heap
 par new generation   total 19136K, used 18399K [7bae00000, 7bc2c0000, 7c0130000)
  eden space 17024K,  95% used [7bae00000, 7bbde7f80, 7bbea0000)
  from space 2112K, 100% used [7bbea0000, 7bc0b0000, 7bc0b0000)
  to   space 2112K,   0% used [7bc0b0000, 7bc0b0000, 7bc2c0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 124636K, used 91349K [7c0130000, 7c7ae7000, 7fae00000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 32468K, used 19605K [7fae00000, 7fcdb5000, 800000000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the AWT-Shutdown thread in your stack dump -- how did you get the AWT into your application? Something has created an AWT object (likely a Window or Frame) and it isn't closed. The SWT has exited but there is still some AWT activity going on.

Comment: Many, many thanks for you answer. I use PrinterJob from awt, to print out PDFDocument. Actually PDFbox does it for me. Do you know a way to get around that?